# class-oembed Error

Tags: oembed

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare _wp_oembed_get_object() (previously declared in /home/samdonme/public_html/wp-includes/embed.php:112) in /home/samdonme/public_html/wp-includes/class-oembed.php on line 692

**embed.php:112**

```
function _wp_oembed_get_object() {
    static $wp_oembed = null;
```

**oembed.php on line 692**

```
function _wp_oembed_get_object() {
    static $wp_oembed = null;

    if ( is_null( $wp_oembed ) ) {
        $wp_oembed = new WP_oEmbed();
    }
    return $wp_oembed;
```

As you see above, I am have problem with the embed.php and class-oembed.php.
When I delete form setting.php

```
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-oembed.php' );
```

problem is fixed. But I want to learn how can I fix "_wp_oembed_get_object()" problem

Comment: the both files should be there in WordPress

Comment: have this any connection with new WordPres version 4.7?

Answer (score 1):

The function `_wp_oembed_get_object` was [moved from `class-oembed.php` to `embed.php` a while back](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/commit/ff592814419a66a5ca933d036f6196318008cb9f#diff-a3ed9145e2e2ed95c0513fe8de0928c4) - your best bet is to [reinstall WordPress](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=reinstall+wordpress).